# Adding A Different Content Area To The Blog Area

Tags: html, css

I hope someone might be able to help me with this. An outsourcer has been working on my site by has made some errors I am trying to sort out.

It looks like the full width template on say http://www.haylockpittman.co.uk/case-studies/family-home-refurbishment-chichester/ is using the same content area (div class entry-content) as the blog posts as it is set to 100%.
You can see the mess it creates on blog posts on http://www.haylockpittman.co.uk/painting-contractors-petersfield/

I am a little stuck (very limited css knowledge) about how I can reduce the area only on the blog posts so that it does not overlap the side bar.
Any guidance with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: add ur html and css code or a fiddle

Comment: ok no need to add fiddle just check my ans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following CSS to the bottom of your themes style.css

```
    .single .entry-content {
        float: left;
        margin: 0 35px 0 0px;
        width: 580px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

your class `.entry-content` has `width:900px`.
just reduce its width to 600px(max);

code:

```
.singular .entry-header, .singular .entry-content, .singular footer.entry-meta, .singular #comments-title 
{
     margin: 0 35px 0 0px;
     width: 600px; /* just change this */
     float: left;
}
```

Comment: I couldnt do that as unfortunatly this was reducing the width of the full width template as well. I have added a .single entry-content from roofdogs advice to the style sheet and it has sorted it. Thanks for taking a look.